# svnrdump E160016 error path not present

Tags: svn

I have created a dump of a svn subtree using svnrdump. The subtree contains a specific project (lets call it 'foo') while I do not have access to the other subtrees being in parallel. The project is accessible (inside the original repo with 'svn://.../Misc/Databases/foo').

Now I want to load that dump into a new repo. Problem is that I always get the error

```
svnrdump: E160016: Path 'Misc' not present
```

The snvrdump call is

```
svnrdump svn://localhost:3691/Misc < repo.dump
```

First I've tried this having a completely empty repository. Second with a freshly created folder 'Misc/Databases' inside the repo - both w/o success.

Exit code of svnrdump is 1.

svnrdump starts with rev 0 and breaks at rev 12838.

Hmm ... I just restarted svnrdump and it looks like it continues with 12839 although I do not know whether this will be successfull.

Any idea how to avoid the initial error?

Thx in advance!

Additional info: no, the restart of svnrdump did not succeed; although the highest rev is around 17000 it now gone beyond 18000 :-(. So still no idea how to import that dump ...

Additional info: acc. to SVN log rev 12838 is the initial one creating my project structure. By looking at the (textual) dump file I see the following line:

```
Node-path: Misc/Databases/foo
```

The new repo contains 'Misc' (part of URL) and also 'Databases' inside 'Misc'.

I'm not sure how to prepare my new repo to get svnrdump running flawlessly ...